# PFFile without PFObject - Parse

Tags: parse-platform, pfobject, pffile

What happens to my `PFFile` if I save it and don't associate it with a `PFObject`?

Does it get lost in the limbo?

Do I have access to it somehow through the Parse dashboard?

Does it count towards my storage limit?

Will it get cleaned up by itself eventually?

Comment: I think PFFiles with no PFObjects get cleaned up every once in a while, but I'm pretty sure you can't access it through the Dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to retrieve it, but it stays within the database. It does count towards your storage limit. It won't clean itself eventually, but you can clean it in your app settings.

[image: PFFile cleanup]

Comment: Just to confirm, now the message is "Click this and we'll clean up all unused files in your account. We'll send you an email when it's done." right? is that the place?

Comment: This is the new message using the beta dashboard. I presume it's the same as the one you're referencing.